# text box that updates with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, textbox, jquery-ui-dialog

After searching for a couple hours on google, I have to turn to stackoverflow once again for answers. Recently, Ive been trying to come up with a some sort of box that updates with lines of text. For example:

---

-getting files  //wait 3 seconds

-storing files  // wait 4 seconds

-sending files // wait 5 seconds

---

Im writing a web application from scratch using c#, asp.net and visual studio.
What I would like to do is create a text box or a window and store the text in an array that will change the text after a certain amount of time.

This does not have to be updated in real time. Its just a project Im working on that provides the "user" with some goof proof data because this process takes a little while. This process will run once the user clicks the submit button. Could anyone here point me in the right direction or get me started? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is the question?  Store text in database or array as string and change the text based on a setTimeout period?

Comment: It's not a poor question by any means, but it could be a lot clearer. I would consider improving the readability a little bit.

Comment: I will edit my question to make more sense. :)

Comment: Are you wanting some sort of Asynchronous processing with a status update? So when it kicks off it says "getting..." then "storing..." then "sending..." depending on the status?

Comment: yes Tim :) the info box does not have to be in sequence with the actual program, but just the constantly changing text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163553.aspx) is very old article about how to update the progress in ASP.NET 2.0.

If you are using Ajax, you may want to try this [AJAX: How to create a "Processing" modal window using UpdateProgress and ModalPopup ASP.net AJAX controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx)

Comment: that first link actually helped alot. Thank you for digging that up.